# How to revert laptop back to default logon page of domain?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, user-accounts

My Neighbour asked me to assist him with his laptop. His wife passed away and he cannot use the laptop because it is password protected, by the company she worked for.  He has no PC or Cell phone and only wants to use the PC to send and receive emails regarding his investments etc.

I loaded a Windows 7 Professional CD to bypass the domain settings (but it installed) and I created a User Profile for him.  However, I no longer have the key for this CD and MS indicates that the PC might be a victim of illegal installation.

I want to uninstall the Windows 7 Professional program, but it does not even show up in the programs.

However, my neighbour now found a piece of paper with a password on - which he would like to try, and now I cannot get back to her original logon page.

How can I "undo" my "creation" to get back to his late wife's login of the Laptop?

He does not really require any of the information or documents on the laptop, so he doesn't mind it being reimaged if we have to.

Comment: Don't abuse the caps lock key please

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the previous installation of Windows and reinstalled, you will not be able to rejoin this machine to the corporate domain without a domain administrator's password (or someone on the Domain with the permission to join).

With regards to this problem, if you had a genuine version of Windows, simply ring Microsoft on the toll free number from the activation screen, explain the situation and they should have no issues activating Windows for you.